# What program is being executed upon time command?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

In my terminal in Ubuntu, I want to execute the `time` program with option `-v`, but it fails:

```
$ time -v ls
-v: command not found
```

However if I specify the path `/usr/bin/time` of the program as such, it works:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ls
foo  bar  baz
        Command being timed: "ls"
        User time (seconds): 0.00
        ...
```

So it seems that `time` and `/usr/bin/time` are different executables.
But to my surprise, when trying to identify `time` with `which`, it tells that it is the same:

```
$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

I am puzzled, can someone explain what is happening?
Is the result of which somehow not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `type time` - it will probably tell you that on your system `time` is a shell keyword (compare this with orher comands like `echo`, `ls` and `nano`).

If you explicitly want to run /usr/bin/time, then type `/usr/bin/time -v ls`

Comment: Yes indeed ```time``` is a shell keyword, I didn't know about those, that's treacherous!

Comment: It's not a keyword, it's a builtin. There is no such thing as a "keyword" in a POSIX shell. There are the *reserved words* `!`, `{`, `}`, `case`, `do`, `done`, `elif`, `else`, `esac`, `fi`, `for`,`if`, `in`, `then`, `until`, and `while` which are reserved in all shells and `[[`, `]]`, `function`, and `select` which are reserved in some shells. As you will notice, `time` is not one of those.

Comment: @JörgWMittag In bash, it's a keyword. See the [Reserved Words section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Reserved-Words). This allows things like applying `time` to [an entire pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (though this is disabled in POSIX mode).

Answer (score 3):

It's both a binary in `/usr/bin/time` *and* a Shell builtin.

```sh
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

Shell builtins have precedence over binaries on disk. To use the binary, you have to specify the path, e.g. `/usr/bin/time -v ls`

The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)) has some more information on the topic.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you for the article.